# Flip Card Activated By Click

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a flip card that flips when clicked (ie not :hover or :activate). No frills yet (besides the shadow, which was in response to a friends challenge), just the basic functionality. I followed various helpful posts on this approach but I can't get it working. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong please?
EDIT: Apologies, had some old code still in there from my work after reading various other posts on here. The code for a checkbox now removed.
EDIT2: Solved it. Needed the jQuery 'ready' method, as added in the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flip Card Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.card').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
    })
})
</script>

<style>
.card {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin: 25px;
perspective: 1000px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: transform 1s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.card.flipped {
transform: rotateY( 180deg );
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.card-front, .card-back {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 25px;
backface-visibility: hidden;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.card-back {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-front">
            The front
        </div>
        <div class="card-back">
            The back
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to check this site out to get more context. It is better to look at another example to find out what is wrong with your code:
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/css/card+animation+css

Comment: the `label` with `class="card"` doesn't have a close tag. try adding that.

Comment: Hi, not sure how the word 'please' had got added to the end of that line but now edited. Still doesn't work though unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you just need to do this

```
$('.card').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
})
```

In any case, this raises a number of questions for me.

1. Why do you need jquery here, you can do it in pure CSS using `:checked`
2. You add a click handler to the class `card`  that you use for both the wrapper and the label, which causes unnecessary triggering of this handler, I would recommend you to give special class names (for example `js-handler-click`) for elements where you need a click handler

```js
$('.card').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
})
```

```css
.card {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin: 25px;
perspective: 1000px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: transform 1s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.card.flipped {
transform: rotateY( 180deg );
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.card-front, .card-back {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 25px;
backface-visibility: hidden;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.card-back {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-front">
        The front
    </div>
    <div class="card-back">
        The back
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Alexandr. See my edit about the mixed code I'd mistakenly posted. Unfortunately, your suggestion for the jquery doesn't help. I'll have to do some more study around the CSS option, as you suggest.

Comment: I forgot to pass `e` as a function parameter in the previous answer, now I wrote a snippet

Comment: Many thanks. Your code snippet does exactly what I'm aiming for when run in situ, unfortunately, when I copy the code in to mine, still no joy. I'm on Win10 and Chrome. I've edited the code above to show your suggestion incorporated. Grateful for the help.

Comment: Maybe you have some errors in the console?

Comment: No console errors. Tried it in Firefox but still no joy. Tried it as a .html file saved in Notepad rather than through ISS (index file in wwwroot).

Comment: Solved as per edit2 to the question above. Thanks for your help.